# What is the definition of an n-ary operation distributing over an m-ary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The distributive property of binary operations is well-known. I want to generalize that definition. For example, I define a unary operation $f$ to distribute over a binary operation $+$ if $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, and a unary operation $f$ to distribute over another unary operation $g$ if $f(g(x))=g(f(x))$. So, motivated by those examples, given a set $S$ and an n-ary operation $f$ on $S$ and an m-ary operation $g$ on $S$, what would be the proper definition of $f$ distributing over $g$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I believe that is the best way to generalize the distributivity definition. You should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that $n$-ary operation $\alpha$ is distributive at its index $i$, $1\le i\le n$ over an $m$-ary operation $\beta$ if

$$\alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_{i−1},\beta(x_{i,1},\ldots,x_{i,m}),x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n)\\=\beta(\alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_{i−1},x_{i,1},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n),\ldots,\alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_{i−1},x_{i,m},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n))$$

for all $x_1,\ldots,x_{i−1},x_{i,1},\ldots,x_{i,m},x_{i+1},\ldots,x_n$. This covers (I think) your cases and also a left ("at index $1$") and right ("at index $2$") distributivity of multiplication over addition.

But, **I** would say that. I don't really know what is the "official" definition, and, besides, how useful the entire concept is.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is definition for this but I would propose

$f(g(x_1^1, ..., x_m^1), ..., g(x_1^n, ..., x_m^n)) = g(f(x_1^1, ..., x_1^n), ..., f(x_m^1, ..., x_m^n))$.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that, for standard distributivity of multiplication over addition, this would mean that $(a+b)(c+d)=ac+bd$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop We should permute arguments then like $f(g(x_1^1, x_2^1), g(x_1^2, x_2^2)) = g(g(f(x_1^1, x_1^2), f(x_2^1, x_2^2)), g(f(x_1^1, x_2^2), f(x_2^1, x_1^2))).$ It is tedious to write this in a general $(m, n)$ case.